# Reward flagging with some reputation

Tags: feature-request, reputation, flags

What about rewarding users that flagged a question with some reputation if the flag was accepted?

So, for example, user A sees a question that is spam (an advertisement) and a moderator accepts this flag, wouldn't it be nice to give the user that flagged the question some reputation (maybe +2 or so).

On the other hand, if user B flaggs a question and the flag was not helpful, and this happens some more time, the user could lose some reputation (-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awarding reputations for flagging question is not a wise point, otherwise users who workout for reputations may flood/spam it.

[Reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) does matter.  But still users are [**awarded with Moderation Badges**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) for their effort in cleaning the StackExchange and making it a better place.

*FYI:* For reviewing suggested edits, they are awarded with +2 rep for each acceptable review(upto 2k rep).

If they audit fails, they will be banned from reviewing for a week.

Comment: The reviewer of suggested edits doesn't get +2 rep — the editor gets +2 rep if the edit is accepted.